# Send SMS on X day

Tags: rules, cron

I have a calendar schedule and within that schedule I have some events. How can I send an SMS to the users on the event day minus some days(event_date - x days)? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on what modules you are using?

Comment: I am using SMS Framework and Clickatel.